# Umbraco: TabsAndPropertiesResolver is not getting recognised

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Iam trying to use

```
Umbraco.Web.Models.Mapping.TabsAndPropertiesResolver
```

method in umbraco custom section api however not able to include it.

```
using Umbraco.Web.Models.Mapping;
TabsAndPropertiesResolver.AddListView(display, "member", Services.DataTypeService, Services.TextService);
```

its showing me error message:

```
Error   61  'Umbraco.Web.Models.Mapping.TabsAndPropertiesResolver' is inaccessible due to its protection level  D:\Umb\Site\Development\Membership\Controllers\MembershipAdminController.cs 163
```

any idea on assembly required for it?

Comment: It seems that the `TabsAndPropertiesResolver` method is `protected` or `private` and therefore, you cannot call it outside the class where it was defined.

Comment: Yep it's an internal class

Comment: Could you give us a bit more of information in order to know what are you trying to achieve? What's the purpose of using that Umbraco internal method?

Comment: Actually i am trying to mimic the member section code where they have list view.So i am trying to get the listview for a custom membership

Comment: Take a look at the umbMemberListView project - may be able to use that as a base for whatever you're trying to do.  https://github.com/robertjf/umbMemberListView

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobertFoster :)